# In a WAP setup using hostapd, how to block Wireless packets using iptables

Tags: filter, iptables, packet, hostapd

I have set up a WAP using hostapd. I would like to block certain types of traffic to go between the hosts connected to the WAP (wireless to wireless). Is it possible to do this using iptables? How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't care too much if your Access Points are set upusing Hostapd or if they are real AP devices. Iptables can block traffice between hosts but at IP level. I mean, if they are only acting as APs and not as routers you can't do what you want. If they are routing traffic you can setup iptables rules to achieve that.

To understand better what I say you must check what is OSI model. Wireless connections are between APs are at layer 2 (data link), and iptables starts acting at level 3 (network).

[image: OSI]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I understand. But I still want to do this. Other than iptables, what else can I use?

Comment: You must set up routing and then use iptables I think.